# A pipe command doesn't work

Tags: command-line, bash

I tried executing this pipe command and it didn't work.

```
find /home/siddath/enron -name "*" -print | \ parallel python email_parser.py {} > from_to.txt 
No command ' parallel' found, did you mean:
 Command 'parallel' from package 'parallel' (universe)
 Command 'parallel' from package 'moreutils' (universe)
 parallel: command not found
```

I installed parallel using

```
sudo apt-get install parallel
```

Output for `apt-cache policy parallel perl` was:

```
parallel:
  Installed: 20130922-1
  Candidate: 20130922-1
  Version table:
 *** 20130922-1 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
perl:
  Installed: 5.18.2-2ubuntu1
  Candidate: 5.18.2-2ubuntu1.1
  Version table:
     5.18.2-2ubuntu1.1 0
        500 htp://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 htp://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
 *** 5.18.2-2ubuntu1 0
        500 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

on running the command `find /home/siddath/enron | parallel python email_parser.py {} > from_to.txt` I get:

```
defined(@array) is deprecated at /usr/local/bin/parallel line 120.
    (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?)
defined(@array) is deprecated at /usr/local/bin/parallel line 580.
    (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?)
defined(@array) is deprecated at /usr/local/bin/parallel line 626.
    (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?)
```

what is the issue?

Update: 
output for `type -a parallel`.

```
parallel is /usr/local/bin/parallel
parallel is /usr/bin/parallel
```

After changing permissions for /usr/local/bin/parallel: `sudo chmod -x /usr/local/bin/parallel`

```
siddath@SID:~/enronscript$ find /home/siddath/enron | parallel python email_parser.py {} > from_to.txt
bash: /usr/local/bin/parallel: Permission denied
```

I navigated to the path as follows:

```
siddath@SID:/usr/local/bin$ find /home/siddath/enron | parallel python email_parser.py {} > from_to.txt 
bash: from_to.txt: Permission denied
```

Do I need to create a file in this directory for executing the find/parallel command or is there another way to make this work?

Comment: For some reason you have a `\<space> ` in your code, just before parallel. Bash probably thinks the command is ` parallel` instead of `parallel` (note the space in front of it).

Comment: Yes, I removed the space after \ and it worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct command should be this:

```
find /home/siddath/enron | parallel python email_parser.py {} > from_to.txt
```

What did I do?

- After the pipe, you wrote `\ parallel` - that is the same as if you ran `' parallel'`, both ways you include a space in the beginning as part of the command. Of course this command does not exist and can therefore not be found. Simply removing the `\`  solves that problem.
- You wrote `find /any/directory -name "*" -print`, but `-print` is already the default action and if no filters are specified, it finds all files and directories - same as with this universal wildcard filter `-name "*"`. So you can omit both parameters and simply write `find /any/directory` instead.

Comment: thanks! that helped :) but now there's nother issue i'm not able to figure out..                                                                                                                                       find /home/siddath/enron | parallel python email_parser.py {} > from_to.txt
defined(@array) is deprecated at /usr/local/bin/parallel line 120.
 (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?)
defined(@array) is deprecated at /usr/local/bin/parallel line 580.
 (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?)

I'M GETTING SOMETHING LIKE THIS (several times).. HAVE TO USE Ctrl+ Z to break out

Comment: This looks like a bug in your version of `parallel` or an incompatibility betwen the script and your installed `perl` version. How did you install `parallel` and what is the output of `apt-cache policy parallel perl`? Please do no post them as comments but edit your question to add the output and notify me with a short comment here when you're done.

Comment: Hi Byte Commander, I've edited my post with the output to the query you asked. Will be grateful if i could find the solution to this asap

Comment: @Madhumita Please do not remove content from your existing question, just add the new stuff as I did. Otherwise my answer would not have made any sense any more... But I don't understand the error. Do you have a different `parallel` file in `/usr/local/bin`? Because that's not its standard location. Please show me the output of `type -a parallel`.

Comment: I have  a parallel in the /usr/local/bin location. made the update as you suggested

Comment: Okay, I don't know what `/usr/local/bin/parallel` is or how it got there, but it's clearly interfering with the real original `/usr/bin/parallel` executable. If you also don't why you got that second file, I would recommend you to make it non-executable. That way it is not removed in case you might need it again, but it does not run instead of the real `parallel` command. Simply run `sudo chmod -x /usr/local/bin/parallel` to remove the execution flag of that second file. Then try your find/parallel command again and check whether you still see error messages.

Comment: i keep getting permission denied. I've updated my post..

Comment: My issue got resolved Byte Commander! I don't know how, I didn't change anything. Thanks a lot for your help!! :D

Comment: @Madhumita Probably it was the reboot. Now `parallel` resolves to the correct executable `/usr/bin/parallel` instead of the old one in `/usr/local/bin`.